# Regex match everything not between a pair of characters

Tags: regex

Suppose a string (representing elapsed time in the format HH:MM:ss) like this:

> "123:59:00"

I want to match everything except the numbers for the minutes, i.e.: the regex should match the bold parts and not the number between colons:

> "**123:** 59 **:00**"

In the example, the 59 should be the only part unmatched.
Is there any way to accomplish this with a js regex?

EDIT: I'm asking *explicitly* for a regex, because I'm using the Notion Formula API and can only use JS regex here.

Comment: Why not just use `.split(':')` and take the first and last elements?

Comment: @Barmar I've edited to explain why I need doing it with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split()` might be the most canonical way to go, but here is a regex approach using `match()`:

```js
var input = "123:59:00";
var parts = input.match(/^[^:]+|[^:]+$/g);
console.log(parts);
```

If you want to also capture the trailing/leading colons, then use this version:

```js
var input = "123:59:00";
var parts = input.match(/^[^:]+:|:[^:]+$/g);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the colons too? e.g.: ["123:", ":00"]

Comment: Yes, use: `input.match(/^[^:]+:|:[^:]+$/g)`

Comment: Thanks! This in addition to the global flag did the trick (wasn't paying attention to the flag till now). If you want to add it to the original aswer, i'm happy to accept this.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to use RegEx for this. Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead.

```js
const timeString = "12:59:00";
const [hours, _, seconds] = timeString.split(":");
console.log(hours, seconds);
```

If you want to use Regex you can use the following:

```js
const timeString = "12:59:00";
const matches = timeString.match(/(?<hours>^\d{2}(?=:\d{2}:))|(?<seconds>(?<=:\d{2}:)\d{2}$)/g);

console.log(matches);

// if you want to include the colons use this
const matchesWithColons = timeString.match(/(?<hours>^\d{2}:(?=\d{2}:))|(?<seconds>(?<=:\d{2}):\d{2}$)/g);
console.log(matchesWithColons);
```

> You can drop the named groups `?<hours>` and `?<seconds>`.

Comment: but I'm asking explicitly for a regex, the thing is i'm using the Notion Formula API and only can use JS regex for that.

Comment: I've upvoted it, just had to change the first `\d{2}` for something like `\d+` to also match for strings like "1:23:45" or "123:45:59". The named groups are nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Could also work

```
^([0-9]{2})\:[0-9]{2}\:([0-9]{2})$/mg
```

Comment: The first part, the hours, could be 1-n digits, my example already shows 3. So that wouldn't work. And even then, the colons aren't matched

Comment: Could then use + or {1,) instead of {2}.

Comment: If you can use capture groups this is a nice solution isn't it. Can easily be adjusted to the needs eg [`^(\d{2,3}:)\d{2}(:\d{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/m5Pouy/1) for the hours part `\d{2,3}`